# readLines only reading header of XML r

Tags: xml, r, rvest

I am downloading and unzipping a gz file that contains an xml. When I use readLines to read the xml into xmlParse, it only returns the header. But in the file there is a full structure

unzipped xml file can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/yonicd/supermarketprices/raw/master/shufersal/Stores7290027600007-000-201505240201.xml)

```
library(hvest)
url.base="http://prices.shufersal.co.il/FileObject/UpdateCategory?catID=0&storeId=0&page="
max.page=as.numeric(gsub("[^1-9]","",html(paste0(url.base,1))%>%html_nodes(xpath="//div[@id='gridContainer']/table/tfoot/tr/td/a[6]")%>%html_attr("href")))
shufersal.url=html(paste0(url.base,max.page))%>%html_nodes("a")%>%html_attr("href")
shufersal.url=shufersal.url[grepl("Store",shufersal.url)]
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(shufersal.url,temp,quiet = T,mode="wb")
readLines(gzfile(temp),encoding = "UTF-8")
  [1] "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
xmlParse(readLines(gzfile(temp),encoding = "UTF-8"))
  Start tag expected, '<' not found
  Error: 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
unlink(temp)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `XML` package capabilities for parsing XML files?

Comment: The file comes as a gz. Then i unzip it and xmlParse reads the readLines output. So i am using XML package. Is there a better way to get to the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#I think you can get the contents without using gzfile (not sure why?);
kk<-readLines(temp,encoding = "UTF-8")
jj<-xmlParse(readLines(temp,encoding = "UTF-8"))
```